# Is a chipped Bundt pan safe to use?

Tags: baking

I’m considering using a chipped, old Nordic Ware Bundt pan - like so:

[image: Chipped Nordic Ware Bundt pan]

The best clue I can get on the material is that the current model of this pan is made using [aluminium with a nonstick coating.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0000CFLM2)

Is there any known risk associated with baking with a chipped inside surface?

Comment: That doesn't look like non stick to me. More like enamel, which used to be very common. It might be steel underneath - test with a magnet. But unless it's flaking off into the food I'd use it. Bare aluminium is widely used in catering, and cake tins are often steel